# How to find Reference time accessing Physical Memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system, paging, tlb

Its a 32 bit system with 2 Level page table, Page size of 4kb p1 = 10bits, p2 = 10bits and offset of 12 bits

Im trying to find the access time to physical memory. Say if it 16 nano seconds and all the pages that are required are in memory. What are the calculations if there is no TLB, or there is a TLB(0.05 nanoseconds access) but doesn't contain the information that is required on the page and there is a TLB(0.05 nanoseconds access) with the info on the page. Can someone help me with this and explain it to me.

Thanks in advance